# scanf confusion with type error

Tags: c, scanf

I just make a program to guess some random pairs in an array,if guess right, delete this pair.

I met a problem that I can only type integer number.Everytime I tried to type like * ,the program will crash. I use a condition like:

```
if (scanf("%d",&temp)==1)
```

to try to fix my problem, but it really does'nt work.

here is my code and please give me some help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    int r[4]; //random
    int s[8]; //store
    char c[8]; //cover
    int g[8]; //guess
    int i;
    int round=0;
    int left = 4;
    int point = 0;
    int clear_index[2];
    int temp;

// generate random number
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    r[i] = (rand()%10)+1;
    s[i] = r[i];
    s[i+4] = r[i];
}
// show the default number
printf("[show]    ");
for (i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    printf("%d ",s[i]);
    c[i] = '*';
}
printf("\n");

while(left>0)
{
    // print left
    printf("[cover]   ");
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%c ",c[i]);
    printf("\n");
    //guess 
    printf("[guess]   ");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d",&temp)==1)
            g[i] = temp;        

        if (g[i] == s[i])
        {
            printf("v\n");
            clear_index[point] = i;
            point++;
        }
    }
    if (point == 2)
    {
        for (i=0;i<2;i++)
            c[clear_index[i]]=' ';
        left-=1;
        point = 0;          
    }
    round+=1;
    //left-=1;
}
printf("you won in %d round",round);
```

}

Comment: this `scanf("%d",&temp)` is meant to get integer numbers that you are typing. Do you want to type either numbers or chars ?

Comment: I try to filter out the non-integer.

Comment: the loop beginning with: `for(i=0;i<8;i++)`  could set up to 8 values into `int clear_index[2];`, but clean_index can only contain 2 values.   I.E. writing beyond the end of the array which invokes undefined behaviour.  This can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the segmentation fault, because, in case, you did not enter an integer, scanf will not return 1, and then, using `g[i]` will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, `g` is a local automatic array variable, and unless initialized explicitly, will have indeterminate value. Attempt to read the value will invoke the UB.

Solution:

1. Always initialize the local variables.
2. In case `scanf()` fails, you need to *eat up* the *invalid* input using some loop like `while (getchar != '\n');` before you proceed to take the next input.

Comment: I am not sure where can I add this while loop? Should I add it before the if (scanf("%d",&temp)==1) ??

Comment: @KennyYang nope. in the else part of the scanf related if statement.

Comment: I am not sure how to eat up those invalid input, I just want to do nothing when the input is invalid.I try like this:
        else 
        {
            char c;
            while((c=getchar())!='\n')
                c = '\n';
        }

Is it correct to eat up invalid input by assigning the input as '\n'??

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a number but the user can place a digit. To prevent this you can use the function [atoi()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) from the library stdlib.h. It converts a string to a integer, if the integer is just number digits, it'll convert it to a integer. If it is a character it will return 0. So you just need to prevent the occurrence of a 0 after the atoi() function is called.